Variablise the file path in VBA formula
Sub CP8PON(CP8Filepath, MCMProductionFile As String)

Dim latrow, objworkbook, objworksheet, Formula1
Const xlUp = -4162

CP8Filepath = CP8Filepath & ".xlsb"

MsgBox MCMProductionFile

Set objworkbook = Workbooks.Open(CP8Filepath)
Set objworksheet = objworkbook.Sheets(1)
Worksheets(1).Activate
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

objworksheet.Range("J1").Value = "Version"

objworksheet.Range("J2:J" & lastrow).Formula = "=+INDEX('" & MCMProductionFile & "'!$G:$G,MATCH(I2,'" & MCMProductionFile & "'!$Q:$Q,0))"

'the below part is working as expected.
'objworksheet.Range("J2:J" & lastrow).Formula = "=+INDEX('C:\Users\VTACSMG\Desktop\CP files\[05_MCM_Production May 2024.xlsb]06_MCM_Production Jun 2024'!$G:$G,MATCH(I2,'C:\Users\VTACSMG\Desktop\CP files\[05_MCM_Production May 2024.xlsb]06_MCM_Production Jun 2024'!$Q:$Q,0))"

Set Rng = Range("J2:J" & lastrow)

End Sub


In the above code, I have to apply formula in column J as shown. I need to pass the workbook path as variable (MCMProductionFile) and the value for the variable is gonna be (C:\Users\VTACSMG\Desktop\CP files\[05_MCM_Production May 2024.xlsb]) in the formula. It will be a parameter for the SUB function.
Currently the commented code is working, whenever trying to variable the path it is not working putting #NA value in the whole J column.
Get the VBS code on how to variablise the file path of workbook in formula  of cell.

Try to add the worksheet name too into the variable.

Did you get the expected string ( file name in square bracket with full path ) with MsgBox MCMProductionFile? You need to pass the sheet name as another argument if it is not a const.

I have tried passing C:\Users\VTACSMG\Desktop\CP files[05_MCM_Production May 2024.xlsb]06_MCM_Production Jun 2024 whole in the variable it didn't worked.

Yes, I did receive the whole path along with sheet name in MSG box  - C:\Users\VTACSMG\Desktop\CP files[05_MCM_Production May 2024.xlsb]06_MCM_Production Jun 2024

Before workbook name a backslash also need.  C:\Users\VTACSMG\Desktop\CP files\[05_MCM_Production May 2024.xlsb]06_MCM_Production Jun 2024

What does Debug.print "=+INDEX('" & MCMProductionFile & "'!$G:$G,MATCH(I2,'" & MCMProductionFile & "'!$Q:$Q,0))" return in Immediate Window? Please, copy the text and paste it here.

Write Formula to Closed Workbook

The two occurrences of !? indicate that you should reconsider how to specify the worksheets.
When a workbook is open, you only specify its name, not its path! Once the source workbook is closed, the path gets automatically added (by Excel).

Sub CP8PON(ByVal CP8Filepath As String)
    
    Const DST_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsb"
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.ActiveSheet ' !?
    ' When a workbook is open, you only specify its name, not its path!!!
    Dim sSheetPath As String:
    sSheetPath = "'[" & swb.Name & "]" & sws.Name & "'!"
    
    ' Destination
    ' It is assumed that the destination ('CP8') file is closed!!!

    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = CP8Filepath
    If StrComp(Right(dFilePath, Len(DST_FILE_EXTENSION)), _
            DST_FILE_EXTENSION, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        dFilePath = dFilePath & DST_FILE_EXTENSION
    End If
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(CP8Filepath)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1) ' !?
    Dim dLastRow As Long:
    dLastRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     
    ' Insert column and write header and formulas.
     
    dws.Columns("J").Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
    dws.Range("J1").Value = "Version"
    dws.Range("J2:J" & dLastRow).Formula = "" _
        & "=INDEX('" & sSheetPath _
        & "'!$G:$G,MATCH(I2,'" & sSheetPath _
        & "'!$Q:$Q,0))"

    'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub

